# Grid doesn't change selected cell after tab key

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, focus

I have the next grid. Plus button have focus and cell selected in the grid(Look at Step 1 at the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8ZLJ.png)).

When I push on Tab key, focus moved to the grid and focused on first cell in the left corner of the grid and old selected cell still selected (Look at Step 2 at the picture).

When I push on Tab key again, focus go to the second cell and old selected cell gone (Look at Step 3 at the picture).

Why does not first cell selected?

[image: grid example]

Comment: Tabbing through the `DataGridView` removes focus and clears the previous selection. To navigate cells while keeping your selections, you should use Shift+Arrow Keys.

Comment: As for Step 2, your "old selection" must have been programmaticaly set to `Selected = true` without the grid ever receiving focus - whereupon tabbing from the button into the grid now selects and highlights the first cell without clearing your selection. If you were to tab all the way through to the last cell, tab out of the grid, and continue tabbing until you again tab into the grid, the last cell would regain focus - not the first. And your previous selection will not be cleared. These are all just default behaviors.